# How to ignore a package while adding a new one to apt-repo?

Tags: php, docker, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` command to install PHP on a server, but it throws something related to Docker:

```
Get:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57.7 kB]
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't need Docker on this server. Not sure who in the past was trying to add Docker. Anyway, I want to ignore Docker, any idea in which place "Docker"  is defined that causes that error? I just need to comment it.

Noted that, I opened this file using nano editor  `nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, but there is nothing related to Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PPAs files are mostly stored under:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

So, you run `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` command to see if there are files like these:

```
docker.list
docker.list.save
```

Then you can just remove them.